# Clear or set WebAssembly module memory buffer

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

I'm working on an issue to clean up all the memory from a webassembly app built with Emscripten. Some related questions without a suitable answer are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70999155/how-to-clear-all-memory-used-in-webassembly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544240/how-can-i-free-memory-allocated-by-rust-code-exposed-in-webassembly?rq=3).

From my understanding, Webassembly memory can only be freed if all JS references to Wasm instance are set to undefined or fall out of scope. In some cases this is proving difficult due to reasons outside my control.

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to set, clear or reset the entire heap on a WebAssembly instance. In this case I no longer need it, it's litereally app cleanup and want to return memory to the browser.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
wasmInstance.buffer = undefined;
```

or

```
wasmInstance.buffer = new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 1});
```

I have tried

```
wasmInstance.HEAPF64 = undefined; 
wasmInstance.HEAPF32 = undefined; 
// ... etc
```

However this only clears the TypedArray views on the webassembly buffer (heap) not the buffer itself.

Comment: I'm not really sure if we can access the entirety of cleaning the heap option via JS/TS. Since you've mentioned the app memory cleanup, you can explore `wasm-gc` option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, a quick google search only turned up this repository for wasm-gc. Is this what you meant? https://github.com/alexcrichton/wasm-gc

Comment: Yes, we used to use it from its CLI crate ([`wasm-gc`](https://docs.rs/crate/wasm-gc/0.1.6))

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to this, and posted it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76513455/303612) which is a related question.

TLDR: allow JS to Garbage Collect the wasmInstance and it will also GC the wasm heap. That's the only way to free wasm memory